# How to get JSON logging with Quarkus and Logback?

Tags: logback, quarkus

I would like to use logback for JSON logging together with Quarkus (1.2.1.Final).

I have put the following *logback.xml* into the resources folder:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <withJansi>false</withJansi>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <provider class="net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.ArgumentsJsonProvider"/>
            <fieldNames>
                <message>logmessage</message>
            </fieldNames>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I'm using this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

However I'm getting no JSON logging.

The logger I am obtaining via (using Kotlin)

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
private val LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing dependencies to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
  <version>6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Docu from https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#including-it-in-your-project

Comment: Hello @yogiginger, I did exactly what you mentioned, but I'm getting the error
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`
Did you add any other log dependency in the pom? 
Thank you!